# Checking if a Button was clicked

Tags: python, pygtk

How can I check if a button was clicked? Could this code work or do I have to use a different command/syntax?

```
def div_clicked(self, button14):
    self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("/"))
    if button14 == "clicked":
        self.equal_clicked()
        self.arithmetic = "division"
```

Especially this line:

```
if button14 == "clicked":
```

I would like to know how can I change the code so the `self.equal_clicked()` function gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your code you can do this form too

```
self.button14.connect("clicked", self.button14_click, "division")

def button14_click(self, button, data):
     self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str("/"))
     self.equal_clicked()
     self.arithmetic = data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My equal_clicked function looks like this                       `def equal_clicked(self, widget):
        if self.rechnung == "plus":
            self.ergebnis = self.erste_zahl + self.zweite_zahl
        elif self.rechnung == "minus":
            self.ergebnis = self.erste_zahl - self.zweite_zahl
        elif self.rechnung == "times":
            self.ergebnis = self.erste_zahl * self.zweite_zahl
        elif self.rechnung == "division":
            self.ergebnis = self.erste_zahl / self.zweite_zahl` Which variables do I have to put inside the brackets?

Comment: None, only delete "widget" from the function parameters because you dont need pass any widget to that function (or pass None)

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged pygtk I assume you are using GTK 2. In this case check out http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-GettingStarted.html#sec-HelloWorld.

This will give you a good starting point on how button clicks and other events are handled. I have pasted a slightly stripped version below:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class HelloWorld:

    # This is a callback function. The data arguments are ignored
    # in this example. More on callbacks below.
    def hello(self, widget, data=None):
        print "Hello World"

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        # Creates a new button with the label "Hello World".
        self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")

        # When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
        # function hello() passing it None as its argument.  The hello()
        # function is defined above.
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.button.show()
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        # All PyGTK applications must have a gtk.main(). Control ends here
        # and waits for an event to occur (like a key press or mouse event).
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello = HelloWorld()
    hello.main()
```